# Getting constraints logs when programmatically centering an image inside UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, constraints, snapkit

I'm tying to create a UIButton with an image inside and I can say that this is working. Just one thing is bothering me and I can't find how to fix this. I'm having a log about a constraint breaking on this element:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001a7ef80 UIImageView:0x7ff2b40aebf0.centerX == UIButton:0x7ff2b4087980.centerX + 6   (active)>",
"<SnapKit.LayoutConstraint:0x600001d7e400@ArgumentInput.swift#109 UIImageView:0x7ff2b40aebf0.centerX == UIButton:0x7ff2b4087980.centerX>"
```

I don't understand why I get the first constraint, I guess this is an automatic one but can't figure how to remove it.

Here is my code (I'm using SnapKit to add constraints) :

```
    self.sendButton.contentEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 12, bottom: 8, right: 12)
    self.sendButton.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.height.width.equalTo(36)
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.snp.centerY)
        make.right.equalTo(self).offset(-5)
    }
    
    
    self.sendButton.imageView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.sendButton.imageView?.snp.makeConstraints { (make) -> Void in
        make.width.equalTo(20)
        make.height.equalTo(20)
        make.centerY.equalTo(self.sendButton)
        make.centerX.equalTo(self.sendButton)
    }
```

Comment: I can't see it in your code, but the error message says you want the Center of the image to be the Center of the button + 6 at the same time as you want the Center of the image to be the Center of the button

Comment: Yes but that +6 isn't something I coded, this is why I can't figure out the issue. I thought that it was some Swift automatic thing or something

Comment: Ok,  I thought that was your own image view, but looking more closely I see it is the button's image view.  You can't add constraints to the button's image view. The button manages that.  Did you perhaps want to add your image as a background image?

Comment: You got it, I removed the constraints on the button's image view and it doesn't show any logs anymore. Thanks!